# どのように配列計算されているのか分からない

Tags: python, tensorflow

下記の関数は画像をマージさせる処理なんですが、

```
img[j*h:j*h+h, i*w:i*w+w, :] = image
```

のコードはどのように配列計算しているんでしょうか。

```
def merge(images, size):
  h, w = images.shape[1], images.shape[2]
  img = np.zeros((h*size[0], w*size[1], 1))
  for idx, image in enumerate(images):
    i = idx % size[1]
    j = idx // size[1]
    img[j*h:j*h+h, i*w:i*w+w, :] = image

  return img
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

プログラムを1行ずつ解説すると煩雑そうなので、ざっくりとしたイメージとして説明します。

まず、引数の `images` は、高さ `h`、幅 `w` の画像たちを一列に並べた配列です。

[image: images の内容の概略図]

`merge` 関数は、この一列に並んだ画像たちを、縦 `size[0]` 個、横 `size[1]` 個となるように並べ替えます。タイルを張り替えるような感覚です。

[image: img の内容の概略図]

ご指摘の

```py
img[j*h:j*h+h, i*w:i*w+w, :] = image
```

という部分では、タイル1枚を `img` に貼ることをしています。つまり、タイルとして見ると縦 `j` 番目、横 `i` 番目の領域に `image` をコピーしています。各 `image` は高さ `h`、幅 `w` なので、`img` の座標で言うと縦 `j*h` から `(j+1)*h`、横 `i*w` から `(i+1)*w` の部分に代入することになります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました。